# telnet script for a group of ip

Tags: ip, telnet

I wanna a script that: telnet to a group of Ip. and after that run a command and save the output in a text. I found some script but isn't suitable for me.

Comment: If the script isn't to big it might be worth to share and explain why that script didn't work or what was missing.

Comment: because it doesnt work automatically.admin should input password.